The content of "that"
Below is a part of the lyrics of "Again" by Shiloh Dynasty.

Baby, oh If I had the money, love 
Would that make you love me? No 
Would that make you love me? Oh, oh, oh

What would native English speakers think is the content of that in the verse?
It seems to me that there are two possiblilities:

the money, and
that I would have the money.

Thank you in advance.

There's little impact on meaning for this context: my money, vs my possession of it. Cf: "We need something fast." "I have a Mustang; is that fast enough?" In that case, "that" = the car, not the possession of the car. Context determines referents.

Thank you Andy-san. Does the money in this context always mean "my" money? And there is no room for interpreting money generally, a holder (not necessarily me) of which  would be a chance to be loved by the lover (you).

Why would someone else's money have any effect on whether you love him? It only makes sense to be talking about the speaker's money. Can you really imagine a song saying"If Joe had the money, would that make you love me?"

Thank you Barmar-san, I would say in that case whom you love is Joe. But I understand that the object is "me."  It seems to me for example that a proverb, "Love me, love my dog." do not necessarily indicate "me" and "my" literally. In a similar manner, I wanted to know the possibility that the verse can be interpreted as anyone who has money can be loved by you (and you are a mammonist).

That is the [pro]nominalisation of "had the money" -> having the money.
Compare "He has been whistling the same tune all day and that really annoys me -> his whistling the same tune.

I had the money --> my having the money

Thank you Greybeard-san. Is it gramatically erroniuous to identify that with the money?

Although It is not grammatically wrong -- Would money make you love me? -- it is semantically wrong.

Thank you again Greybeard-san. As Andy-san said above, I would agree that there is little impact on meaning for this context if the money in the 1st verse can indicate my money. However, I can understand the sentence, "Would money make you love me?" is somewhat wired.

The key point is that the quotation is the lyric of a song. So, though in strictly grammatical terms it is possible to take the demonstrative pronoun 'that' as referring to either the fact expressed in "I have the money", or to the stuff referred to by the noun phrase "the money".
Whether "that" refers to the money itself or the poet's possession of it, or whether they amount to the same thing and the difference does not matter requires more information than the lines quoted. The only lyric I can find involve one verse and one refrain, neither of which is decisive.

Thank you Tuffy-san. Impression held from the comments here leads me to the conclusion that native English speakers are likely (natural) to refer the 'that' to 'my having the money.'
